# How can I create a type that I can use in order to assert that each of the methods in a class return a Promise?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

How can I create a type that I can use in order to assert that each of the *methods* in `Test` return a Promise?

This is what I have so far:

```
void (async function(){

class Test {
    public a = 1;
    methodA(a: number) {
        return a;
    }
    
    methodB(b: string) {
        return b;
    }
}

type FunctionType<T extends object> = { [k in keyof T]: T[k] extends (...args: any) => any ? k : never }[keyof T];

type TestWithAsyncMethods<T extends object> = {
    [k in FunctionType<T>]: (...args: Parameters<T[k]>) => Promise<ReturnType<T[key]>>;
};

const test = <TestWithAsyncMethods<Test>><unknown>new Test();

const resultA = await test.methodA(1); // methodA: (a: number) => Promise<number>
console.log(resultA);

const resultB = await test.methodB('test'); // methodB: (b: string) => Promise<string>
console.log(resultB);
})();
```

The error is:

```
error TS2344: Type 'T[k]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.
  Type 'T[FunctionType<T>]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
    Type 'T[T[keyof T] extends (...args: any) => any ? keyof T : never]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
      Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
        Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
          Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.

229     [k in FunctionType<T>]: (...args: Parameters<T[k]>) => Promise<ReturnType<T[k]>>;
```

Comment: One approach is as: `type TestWithAsyncMethods<T extends object> = {
    [k in FunctionType<T>]: (...args: Parameters<T[k] extends (...args: any) => any ? T[k] : never>) => Promise<ReturnType<T[k] extends (...args: any) => any ? T[k] : never>>;
};`

Comment: Based on the question title, I think you're looking for something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3oVbm) constrained identity function. If that answers your question, I can write it up as one including an explanation. If not, what did I miss?

Comment: However, I would like to figure out a more concise way to write that.